multiple classes in one model file - Laravel 11
**app\models\categories.php**

<?pp
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class categories extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
 
}

class users extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
 
}


**app\http\controllers\category.php
**

<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

use App\Models\categories;
 
class category
{
    public static function category_list()
    {
        $posts = categories::all();
        return($posts);
    }

    public static function single_data($ret_dat)
    {
        $posts1 = categories::where('id','>',$ret_dat)->firstOrFail();
        return($posts1);
    }
}

class users
{
    public static function users_list()
    {
        $user_list = users::all();
        return($user_list);
    }

    
}

**resources\views\category.blade.php**

<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\category;

$users = users::users_list();
echo "Full Users <br>";
foreach($users as $users_li)
{
  echo $users_li->id." -- ".$users_li->name;
}

Getting Error of 'Class "users" not found'. Can anybody help to solve this issue?
Getting Error of 'Class "users" not found'. Can anybody help to solve this issue? everything works fine other than this error. The first class category works fine. the second class is not working.

You can't have multiple classes inside a single file in Laravel due to the way the autoloader works.
If you have a Category class inside the namespace App\Models, then the autoloader will try to autoload this model from the path app/Models/Category, as you can see the name of the file is identical to the name of the class contained inside it, and there's no way the autoloader will know how to load the other class (in case it exists).
For more information, read about the PSR-4 standard.
Aside from that, it's generally a good practice to keep each class inside a separate file because it helps you keep things organized.
